# Is it true that if $x \ge 2000$, then the least common multiple of $\{1,2,3,\dots,x\}$ is greater than $2.499^x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple, chebyshev-function

As I was reading through Jitsuro Nagura's [proof](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195570997), I am seeing that he showed for $x \ge 2000$:

$$\psi(x) \ge 0.916x$$

where $\psi(x) = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\vartheta(\sqrt[m]{x})$ and where $\vartheta(x) =\sum\limits_{p\le x}\log p$

Let $\text{lcm}(x) = $ the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $\{1,2,3,\dots,x\}$.

Doesn't this imply that for $x \ge 2000$:
$$\text{lcm}(x) \ge e^{0.916x} \ge (e^{0.916})^{x} > (2.499)^x$$

Am I misunderstanding Nagura's classic result?

Comment: yes, $\psi$ really is the natural log of the LCM

Comment: Thanks!  I wanted to make sure that I was interpreting the result correctly.